# Infopath cannot generate a form template sharepoint 2013 Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, infopath, infopath-form

Hi Please do help me for this, I am not able to custemize infopath form on click ribbon Customize button [image]

I am Getting the below issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also able to reproduce this issue.

The issue will come when we click on the **Customize in Infopath** link from the list ribbon. [image: Infopath Form Opening Issue3]

[image: Infopath Form Opening Issue]

**Solution**:

Open the form in another way by below navigation,

Go List **Settings** Page -> Click on the **Form Settings** link -> **select Customize the current form using Microsoft InfoPath** -> Click on the **OK** button.

[image: Infopath Form Opening Issue4]

**Notes**:

- If you open the list first time in InfoPath form, you will get this option - **select Customize the current form using Microsoft InfoPath**
- If you already open the list in InfoPath form and trying to open second time(second time onwards), you will get this option - **Modify the existing InfoPath form**

Now the form got opened, without any issues:

[image: Infopath Form Opening Issue2]

If still, you face the issue, you may check below:

Make sure you are not clicking on the list while it is in a datasheet view mode - if so, change, it to normal view mode and open it.

If still does not work.

Some of the columns schema might have unbounded with the list like recently any columns data type has been changed, so in this case, try to revert the data type to the previous one.

Comment: Whatever you explained above editing through list settings is working fine, but through ribbon button not able to.

Comment: Hi - That is known issue

Comment: I am trying in windows server 2010

Comment: That is not helped for me. My question is regarding to ribbon button customize info-path.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on Windows 10 related to the update listed in KB [4489886](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4489886/windows-10-update-kb4489886), and is documented under the section "Known issues in this update".

For workarounds, please refer to the following article:

[SoapServerException error when customizing list form (SPO and SP-onprem) using InfoPath designer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/infopath/soapserverexception-when-customizing-list-form-using-infopath-designer)